# javascript algorithm to auto fit multiple images

Tags: javascript, css, html, algorithm

I was looking for a function which would take the **overall width, max height, min height** parameters as the input and fit multiple images in the given overall width adjusting their width.

So for an example in this [page](https://jsbin.com/xahulut/1/) , all the images (**in same row**) should get auto adjusted to the same height keeping their original aspect ratio with javascript changing their widths.

**Edit: I have Answered**

Comment: check this http://masonry.desandro.com/layout.html

Comment: masonry does not keep the images in the same height in a row

Comment: you want the images to get stretched to fill the row up?

Comment: @Purag keeping the aspect ratio, yes, with the same height in a row

Comment: so you want to continue increasing the width and height, keeping the ratio, until the row width is filled? and obviously (i'm hoping), each row can have a different height?

Comment: and one more question: will the container always have fixed width?

Comment: @Purag yes increase the width but not continuously, the function should have a max height constraint.

Comment: @Purag will the container always have fixed width?  No the javascript function as I mentioned in the question, it has all the answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer so that images are of constant height and fills the outer div.

The example [here](https://output.jsbin.com/kinaheg/1)

The javscript here -

```
$(function(){

//var pics;

var pic1 = {height:"10", width:"20", ap:1.374, rh:0};
var pics = [pic1];

//pics.push(pic3);

//$('#test').html(pics[2].height);

$('#some').imagesLoaded(function() {

$('#test').html('test ');
$('#some img').each(function(index) {    
  //setting const height
  $(this).height(150);
  var apic = {height:$(this).height() , width: $(this).width() ,ap: $(this).width() / $(this).height() , rh:0};
  pics.push(apic);


});

$('#test').append(pics.length+ '<br />');

for (var j=1; j <pics.length;j++) {

  $('#test').append(pics[j].width  + ' ' + pics[j].ap + '<br />');
}
$('#test').append('Calculating width ' + '<br />');
var set = [0];

for (var j=1; j <pics.length;j++) {


  var t = 0;
  var c = j
  do {        
    t = t+ pics[c].width;
    $('#test').append(c + ' ' + t+ '<br />');
    c=c+1;
  }while (t < 645 && c<pics.length);
  c=c-1;
  if(t>645) {
    c = c -1;
  }

  set.push(c);
  j = c;

}    
$('#test').append('Sets are: <br />');
var v = 1;
var st = 0;
for (p = 1; p<set.length; p++) {

  $('#test').append(set[p] + ' ');      
  st = v;
  v = set[p];
  $('#test').append(p + ': ');

  var tot = 0;
  var inc = 0;
  while(tot < 645 ) {
    var tot1=0;
    for(var g = st; g<v+1; g ++) {
      tot1 =tot1+ (pics[g].ap * (pics[g].height+inc));

    }
    tot=tot1;
    inc = inc+1;
  }
  for(var g = st; g<v+1; g ++) {
      $('#some img').eq(g-1).height ( 150 + inc);        
  }

  $('#test').append( '<br / >');
  v = v+1;


}

$('#test').append('<br />'); 



/*
var tot = 0
var wid;
var wid1;
var inc=0;
var r = 1;
for (r =1; r<pics.length-1; r++) {
  inc = 0;
  tot = 0;
while ( tot < 645) {

  wid = pics[r].ap * (pics[r].height+inc);
  wid1 = pics[r+1].ap * (pics[r+1].height+inc);

  tot = wid + wid1;
  inc = inc+ 1;
}


$('#test').append('Total ' + inc +' '+ wid  + ' ' + wid1 + '<br />');    
$('#some img').eq(r-1).height ( 150 + inc);
$('#some img').eq(r).height ( 150 + inc);
  r=r+1;
  */
}
);




 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need only to change the height of the picture. The aspect ratio remains.

```js
function height100() {
    var imgages = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(imgages, function (a) {
        a.style.height = '100px';
    });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="height100();">100px height</button><br>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200/">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/150/">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/200/">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/200/">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/">
```

Comment: This does not fill overall width. Can you show any example page?

Answer (score 0):

You dont necessarily need JS to accomplish this, unless your height is dynamic.

Flexbox should be able to take care of it for you.

Here is what you could do.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/150/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/">
</div>
```

If you are looking for a dynamic height, just set the height at run time and could do something like this.

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');

[].forEach.call(imgs, function(img) {
  img.style.height = "100px";
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
img {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/150/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/200/">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/250/">
</div>
```

Comment: This does not take care of the overall width.

Comment: What exactly you mean it doesn't care overall width?

Comment: as in the question it should adjust the images height such that the width equals the width of the div, the bordered outer div if you see in the example in the question. I will just post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answers, it's a trivial job to adjust images to have the same height. Once you have scaled the images to have same height, according to their individual aspect ratio they will have different widths. Assuming that you have a certain width per row of images you might do as follows to distribute the images to the rows such that rows evenly get populated with the maximum amount of image and minimum white space.

```js
function lineUpImages(imageWidths,totalWidth){
  var  sum = imageWidths.reduce((p,c) => p+c),
       avg = sum/imageWidths.length;
   initial = [...Array(Math.ceil(avg))].map(sa => (sa = [], sa.sum = 0, sa)); // initial rows array
  return imageWidths.sort((a,b) => b-a)
                    .reduce((lines,image) => { var line = lines.reduce((p,c) => p.sum < c.sum ? p : c);
                                               line.push(image);
                                               line.sum += image;
                                               return lines;
                                             },initial);
}

var imageWidths = [...Array(20)].map(_ => ~~(Math.random()*4)+2), // generate a random array of image width values
         result = lineUpImages(imageWidths,20); // maximum row width allowed is 20
console.log("Image Widths: :", JSON.stringify(imageWidths));
console.log("Rows:", JSON.stringify(result));
```

You might also chain up a map instruction to the very end and shuffle the images in each row (shuffling the sub arrays).